# Archives from previous versions of Xcode in the Organizer

Tags: xcode, archive, organizer

After updating to XCode 4.3, all my archives built using XCode 4.2 are gone.  The recently built ones are there.

Where are they?  I would like to get them in the organizer so I can symbolicate crash logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archives are stored at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives in dated folders. I don't know how long this has been true, but it's been true since at least October 2011, because I still have some archives from then. If your old archives exist anywhere, they should be at this location.

If they are missing, and you have Time Capsule backups enabled, you should still be able to recover the archives from your Time Capsule backups.